# Relating to commenting a block of JSX code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, window, comments, prettier

does Prettier extension allowed me to comment a block of JSX code in Visual Studio Code?

Before installing Prettier extension and ES7+ extension, i could not comment out a block of JSX code with "   Ctrl + '/' ", but after i installed those two, i could do that, i wonder if it is Prettier that allows me to.